# which layout is best for moving buttons within

Tags: android, android-layout

OK first I'm not actually moving buttons I'm moving imageviews that have an onclick listener. What I want to do is drag multiple imageviews around inside a layout. I was going to use a FrameLayout but it seems that wont work for multiple items.
Can anyone tell me which layout is suitable for this?

thanks in advance

Comment: it depends on you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearlayout with a vertical orientation should do it for you..use margain_direction for fine tuning it further

Comment: but the different image views should be able to be to the side of or above/below the other image views

Comment: You can place them as you need by nesting layouts i could give you a code example if needed.

Comment: Nevermind It wasnt difficult using framelayout i didnt realise i could use margins

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a GridLayout would suit your needs? You can have one or multiple child views in each grid cell.